# How to use google ClientLogin with the 1.7 version of the Google Client API

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, google-client

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Google ClientLogin API from Java.

The problem I have is that the code below throws an exception:

*java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No parser defined for Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:461)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.clientlogin.ClientLogin.authenticate(ClientLogin.java:191)*

From what I can fathom I need to set some parsers into my Transport object.  All the examples I can find on the Web either use a GoogleTransport (which was deprecated prior to 1.7) or they use a HttpTransport but call an 'addParser()' method which doesn't seem to be there anymore either (talk about a moving target) or they create their own subclass of HttpTransport and set a parser in the override constructor (however the examples I find for this use GoogleUtil class which I don't seem to have in my api package even though I'm pretty sure I included all the dependant jar files).

Any suggestions on how to do this?  (I know I could use the raw protocol directly and kind of wish I had but thought the ClientLogin class would be a quick and simple solution).

Code that is being used to call the ClientLogin is below.

```
//Note I've checked that googleUserName and googlePassword are set
System.out.println("logging in for:" + googleUserName + "," + googlePassword);
ClientLogin clientLogin = new ClientLogin();
clientLogin.accountType = "HOSTED_OR_GOOGLE";
clientLogin.applicationName = "MyCompany-LoginProxy-version-0.1";
clientLogin.username = googleUserName;
clientLogin.password = googlePassword;
clientLogin.authTokenType = "apps";


com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();

clientLogin.transport = transport;
clientLogin.serverUrl = new GenericUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin");
ClientLogin.Response loginResponse = clientLogin.authenticate();
```

For reference as well this is the import statements at the top of the file:

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.clientlogin.*;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonRpcHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.apache.ApacheHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpParser;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleHeaders;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.*;
```

And I'm using the 1.7-beta version of the google client library (java)

Also side note - I know that OAuth is the recommended approach - and I implemented it initially - but it is not proving suitable for the requirement I'm addressing.

Comment: Side note - I implemented it using the raw protocol successfully now but still curious how to use the ClientLogin to do it.